# How to correctly use iOS Runtime Headers in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, runtime, iphone-privateapi

How can I correctly use the [iOS runtime headers](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers) inside Xcode for apps that won't make it to the App Store but just for personal hacking?

For example, do I copy the frameworks to `/System/Library` on my Mac or just include the required dumped runtime-headers to my Xcode project? If so how can I make the including work since when included, I get a ton of error messages. I am drawing a blank here.

There is some stuff on the web but nothing clearly stated. A detailed explanation would be much appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**First lets start by how to link those frameworks**

lets assume you want to use SpringBoardServices framework

1. go to https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/ and download the headers
2. search for **SpringBoardServices.framework** folder and copy all headers inside
3. go to */Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework* 
   and create a folder named **Headers**

> replace **iPhoneOS.platform** with **iPhoneSimulator.platform** an paste the headers in simulator SDK folder too if you want to try apps on the simulator

4. paste the files you just copied inside

> Now you can link the SpringBoardServices Framework

**Now how to use SpringBoardServices**

This will open the mail application

```
#include <SpringBoardServices/SpringBoardServices.h>
void openMailApp(){
    SBSLaunchApplicationWithIdentifier(CFSTR("com.apple.MobileMail"), false);
};
```

To get the name of the app that currently playing music use

```
SBSCopyNowPlayingAppBundleIdentifier();
```

Comment: I did exactly what you've explained but Xcode is complaining about being unable to find `SpringBoardServices.h`.

Comment: when you open that directory you should see a file named SpringBoardServices.tbd try including it to Xcode then import the headers to your project directly

Comment: when you pass headers paste them inside Headers folder not the SpringBoardServices.framework folder paste the in SpringBoardServices.framework/Headers